# em1: watchdog timeout -- resetting virtualbox

Tags: configuration, virtualization, virtualbox, freebsd

everyone. 
I try to configure network adapter of my freebsd on virtualbox machine. At first setting up, I got it right. However, after a couple of reboots, my VM gives me a error message: says "em1:Watchdog timeout -- resetting"

I tried to google it, and there is no solution that works for me.

The following is my network adapter of my VM:

- Apapter1: NAT
- Adapter2: Host-only Adapter vboxnet0

On my Virtualbox setting:
Host-only networks:
Adapter:

- IPv4 address: 192.168.56.10
- IPv4 network mask: 255.255.255.0

On my FreeBSD VM /etc/rc.conf

- ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
- ifconfig_em1="inet 192.168.56.11 netmask 255.255.255.0"

Moreover, strange thing is that, 
for example, if timeout error message show at ttyv0 ,
when I log in at different ttyv[1-9], the error message will not be shown.
but in ttyv0, it still gives me the message.

And, in term of functionality of em1, it does work.

I have no clue about this problem. Hoping any one can give me a solution or suggestion. 
That will be great! Thanks a lot.

Freebsd version:  9.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE  i386
Virtual box: 4.1.2 r73507

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD? Which version of vbox?

Comment: Regarding the kernel log messages appearing on ttyv0 and not the others, this is by design - the default config for syslogd (in /etc/syslog.conf) has it write messages from the kernel to /dev/console, which points to ttyv0 by default (see conscontrol(8)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem in the past. It wasn't to do with FreeBSD it was an issue with the Virtualbox adapters supplied to the guest. FreeBSD is just showing you that there is an inconsistency between systems.

Initially I was using the Intel adapters in Virtualbox.
I simply changed the driver for each adapter under settings > network > adapter to "PCnet-PCI II". Then the networking was stable and consistent.